# getJSON denies parameter count

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I'm using getJSON to get data from an external server, this is for building an app. In Firefox on my desktop this works fine:

`jQuery.getJSON("http://www.url.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug=slug&count=10&callback=?",
  function(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, '    '));
});`

but on a mobile browser (tested multiple) the parameter count seems to be overruled and set to a default of 5.

Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: for cross-domain `json` call see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849802/jquery-getjson-works-locally-but-not-cross-domain

Comment: I have already tested this:   $.ajax({
   url: 'http://www.url.com/api/get_category_posts/',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   data: {
    slug: 'slug',
    count: 10
   },
with the same result.

Comment: How do you find the parameter count ? Give specific example.