# Converting php json to javascript getJSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Hello stackoverflow community, i'm apologising for my ignorance in javascript/ajax but i have a hard time to convert this php json into a javascript function

```
$json =    file_get_contents('http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/videos/mail/alex.costantin/_myvideo/4375.json');
$json_a = json_decode($json,true);
$url = $json_a[videos][0][url];
$img = $json_a[meta][poster];
echo $url;
echo $img;
```

Thanks in advance for any help given

**Var_dump Json**

```
string(984) "{"version":3,"service":"mail","provider":"ugc","author":{"email":"alex.costantin@mail.ru","name":"alex.costantin","profile":"http://my.mail.ru/mail/alex.costantin"},"meta":{"title":"avg","externalId":"mail/alex.costantin/_myvideo/4375","itemId":4375,"accId":54048083,"poster":"http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/file/sc03/2500725436577747223","duration":7955,"url":"http://my.mail.ru/mail/alex.costantin/video/_myvideo/4375.html","timestamp":1430140403,"viewsCount":13345},"videos":[{"key":"360p","url":"http://cdn28.my.mail.ru/v/54048083.mp4?sign=dab566053f09db40a63a263f17190aeeb09f1d8d&slave[]=s%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5010%2F54048083-v.mp4&p=f&expire_at=1430773200&touch=1430140403","seekSchema":3},{"key":"720p","url":"http://cdn28.my.mail.ru/hv/54048083.mp4?sign=e9ea54e857ca590b171636efae1b80ccdf0bb5bf&slave[]=s%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5010%2F54048083-hv.mp4&p=f&expire_at=1430773200&touch=1430140403","seekSchema":3}],"encoding":true,"flags":16387,"spAccess":3,"region":"200"}"
```

**Var_dump Json_a**

```
array(10) { ["version"]=> int(3) ["service"]=> string(4) "mail" ["provider"]=> string(3) "ugc" ["author"]=> array(3) { ["email"]=> string(22) "alex.costantin@mail.ru" ["name"]=> string(14) "alex.costantin" ["profile"]=> string(37) "http://my.mail.ru/mail/alex.costantin" } ["meta"]=> array(9) { ["title"]=> string(3) "avg" ["externalId"]=> string(33) "mail/alex.costantin/_myvideo/4375" ["itemId"]=> int(4375) ["accId"]=> int(54048083) ["poster"]=> string(56) "http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/file/sc03/2500725436577747223" ["duration"]=> int(7955) ["url"]=> string(62) "http://my.mail.ru/mail/alex.costantin/video/_myvideo/4375.html" ["timestamp"]=> int(1430140403) ["viewsCount"]=> int(13345) } ["videos"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(4) "360p" ["url"]=> string(185) "http://cdn28.my.mail.ru/v/54048083.mp4?sign=dab566053f09db40a63a263f17190aeeb09f1d8d&slave[]=s%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5010%2F54048083-v.mp4&p=f&expire_at=1430773200&touch=1430140403" ["seekSchema"]=> int(3) } [1]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(4) "720p" ["url"]=> string(187) "http://cdn28.my.mail.ru/hv/54048083.mp4?sign=e9ea54e857ca590b171636efae1b80ccdf0bb5bf&slave[]=s%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5010%2F54048083-hv.mp4&p=f&expire_at=1430773200&touch=1430140403" ["seekSchema"]=> int(3) } } ["encoding"]=> bool(true) ["flags"]=> int(16387) ["spAccess"]=> int(3) ["region"]=> string(3) "200" }
```

So far i've made this but no success, what's wrong with the code?

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/videos/mail/alex.costantin/_myvideo/4375.json", async: false, beforeSend: function(x) { if(x &amp;&amp; x.overrideMimeType) { x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8"); } }, dataType: "json", success: function(data){ alert(data.meta.poster); }});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849861/3859027

Comment: @Ghost this json url doesn't support callback, can you make me a example similar to my php json code?

Comment: then just make a php wrapper which gets it, then call you PHP url instead

Comment: @Ghost can you give me a example? I don't get it, as far as i can see you understand well ajax, can you please make me a working example on jsfiddle? Thanks

Comment: Can you `var_dump` the `$json` and `$json_a` variables and post them for review?

Comment: @SethMcClaine i have updated the question with the var_dump's

Comment: Its been a little while since I've used php but dont you still have to put your array keys in quotes? `$json_a["videos"][0]["url"]` and `$json["metal"]["poster"]`

Comment: **`$json["meta"]["poster"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't get it thru JSONP, you could just create that PHP wrapper that handles the request, then call that PHP url of yours to get it.

Here's a rough example on the same page (of course, it would be much better if you separate the PHP file).

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['json_call'])) {
    echo file_get_contents('http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/videos/mail/alex.costantin/_myvideo/4375.json');
    exit;
}

?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: document.URL,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {json_call : true},
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response.version);
        alert(response.videos[0].key);
    }
});
</script>
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/l5skpk)

Comment: @Ilie sure no prob, glad this helped

Comment: @Ilie if you used `$.getJSON` then it wouldn't work of course, that sends a `GET` request, i'm my example, i used POST

Comment: i haven't used $.getJSON, i need to use it beacuse if not it get's the data from server side, i need from client side, like this one is made take a look [link](http://www.movietend.com/player-moby.php?oid=97788243&id=163494721&hash=877e091877cd7a11)

Comment: @Ilie haven't you tried out the demo, should be faily straight forward, the PHP get the external JSON, then your clientside (JS) calls your PHP instead

Comment: i did like that but i need to request the content from client side with ajax/javascript than make your code work out, i just need to pull the data from url by client side, can you change your code to work like that, instead of file_get_contents server side to $.getJSON client side?

Comment: @Ilie just use `echo file_get_contents($_GET['oid'])`

Comment: i've explained myself badly, so, `echo file_get_contents($_GET['oid'])` is not a option because i will get content from my server's side, the [Json Video Url](http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/videos/mail/alex.costantin/_myvideo/4375.json) gives diferent data to every client, and that's why i need to retrieve this data from client side with `$.getJSON` i hope you understood my intentions

Comment: Hi @Ghost i've made this `$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/videos/mail/alex.costantin/_myvideo/4375.json",
     async: false,
     beforeSend: function(x) {
      if(x &amp;&amp; x.overrideMimeType) {
       x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
      }
 },
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(data){
 alert(data.meta.poster);
 }});` but doesn't works, what's wrong with the code?

Comment: @Ilie yes it won't work, its cross origin policy, you can't do that. you need to use PHP to call the external JSON, then use your own JS to call your PHP that calls the external JSON if you can't use JSONP

Comment: Hi @Ghost how can i call the external json from client side?

Comment: @Ilie you can't since you said that this external JSON doesn't support callback. that server needs to support it first

Comment: but i wonder how http://en.savefrom.net/ does because they use java and you can download videos from mail.ru there must be a trick to get the json from client side

Comment: @Ilie i've already answered that, the trick is use your PHP to call the JSON outside your domain, and then use the JS to call your PHP that called the external JSON. i know its not a one way route, but it works

Comment: what do you mean by calling the json outside my domain? can you make me a example please?

Comment: @Ilie its already my answer, and the answer of alexis below, it actually shows the same thing. use your PHP to call the external JSON, then call that PHP using your JS, it seems we're not getting through you

Comment: you don't understand what i mean, look i've made the json to be called from ouside my domain, but my domain still makes the file_get_contents meaning that it will get data based on my domain ip request, so this means that the `+videos[0].url+` will not work to the client [Look at this raw](http://www.movietend.com/datas/raw.php?oid=http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/videos/mail/alex.costantin/_myvideo/4375.json)  and take the .mp4 link and you'll see that is not working! i need to request the json data from client side directly!

Answer (score 1):

I think its just the way you are accessing the variables, you need to use quotes around your keys

```
<?php
   $json = '{"version":3,"service":"mail","provider":"ugc","author":{"email":"alex.costantin@mail.ru","name":"alex.costantin","profile":"http://my.mail.ru/mail/alex.costantin"},"meta":{"title":"avg","externalId":"mail/alex.costantin/_myvideo/4375","itemId":4375,"accId":54048083,"poster":"http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/file/sc03/2500725436577747223","duration":7955,"url":"http://my.mail.ru/mail/alex.costantin/video/_myvideo/4375.html","timestamp":1430140403,"viewsCount":13345},"videos":[{"key":"360p","url":"http://cdn28.my.mail.ru/v/54048083.mp4?sign=dab566053f09db40a63a263f17190aeeb09f1d8d&slave[]=s%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5010%2F54048083-v.mp4&p=f&expire_at=1430773200&touch=1430140403","seekSchema":3},{"key":"720p","url":"http://cdn28.my.mail.ru/hv/54048083.mp4?sign=e9ea54e857ca590b171636efae1b80ccdf0bb5bf&slave[]=s%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A5010%2F54048083-hv.mp4&p=f&expire_at=1430773200&touch=1430140403","seekSchema":3}],"encoding":true,"flags":16387,"spAccess":3,"region":"200"}';

  $json_a = json_decode($json,true);

  var_dump($json_a["meta"]["poster"]); 
  //string(56) "http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/file/sc03/2500725436577747223"
?>
```

to set a js variable with your php you can do this:

```
<script>
    var poster = '<?php echo $json_a["meta"]["poster"]; ?>';
</script>
```

to set a js object with your php you can do this:

```
<script>
    var jsonString = '<? phpfile_get_contents('http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/videos/mail/alex.costantin/_myvideo/4375.json'); ?>';
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
</script>
```

Comment: actually, the OP wants to process this JSON in javascript

Comment: and the issue isn't in the JS  in their example

Comment: yes the quotations  need to be there but the OP said that: _but i have a hard time to convert this php json into a **javascript function**_ of course your answer would work on the PHP side, but the OP wants the values processed inside JS

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Simple JSON for PHP](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP) library to forge your complex JSON and merge multiple json together without decoding them.

```
<?php

  include('../includes/json.php');

  // $json = new json(); // Pure JSON
  $json = new json('callback', 'myCallback'); // JSON with Callback

  $jsonOnly = file_get_contents('http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/videos/mail/alex.costantin/_myvideo/4375.json');

  $json->add('status', '200');

  if(connected){
    $json->add("alex.constantin", $jsonOnly, false);
    $json->add("authorized", true);
    // $json->add("authorized"); can also be used
  }
  else 
    $json->add("authorized", false);

  $json->send();
?>
```

In your HTML you can mainly call it via 2 ways :

#### Legacy JS & DOM elements.

The callback must be "integrated" with something like : `mycallback({ ... });`

```
function load_script(url) {
  var s = document.createElement('script'); 
  s.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}

function load_scripts() {
  load_script('myPhpPage');
}

window.onload=load_scripts;
```

#### Ajax via Legacy JS or via JQuery

The callback should be like : `{}` and is called so :

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/MyPHP.php',
data,
function(json) {
  alert(json);
});
```

Comment: The content is different for every client, based on ip address, the @Ghost answer was good but i need to get it via client side with `$.getJSON`

Comment: Then, as I just said : use `$.getJSON`, `$.ajax`, `$.post`, `$.get` to send data (could be a unique token) and retrieve the response. In your PHP, you just have to add some conditions, like verifying the token sent and forging the JSON only if the user is authorized. You can add any object, string, array, number, bool or JSONString via the `Simple JSON for PHP` library

Comment: can you make me a example how can i make this ? I'm really new in ajax/javascript

Comment: This is not in the Javascript where we have to work, but in the PHP part. You CANNOT decide if you are connected in Javascript because the client could add some malicious data. JS can be modified by the client. First : Create your PHP script that make you able to check if you are connected & sending a token (stocked in the SESSION var & the COOKIE)

Comment: i've made this `$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "http://videoapi.my.mail.ru/videos/mail/alex.costantin/_myvideo/4375.json", async: false, beforeSend: function(x) { if(x &amp;&amp; x.overrideMimeType) { x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8"); } }, dataType: "json", success: function(data){ alert(data.meta.poster); }});` but doesn't works, what's wrong with the code?

Comment: I say you again, FIRST make your PHP.

Verify by loading the page that the information you get is correct!