# Making a simple API call with jQuery getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, getjson

I am trying to build a simple Random Quote Generator in Codepen as you can see here: http://codepen.io/scabbyjoe/pen/dXQmLw

Relevant code pasted below:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Random Quote Machine</h1>
        <div class="quote">
        </div>
        <div class="btn">New Quote</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").on("click", function(){
        $.getJSON("http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en", function(json) {
            $(".quote").html(JSON.stringify(json));
        });
    });
});
```

I am afraid I must be misunderstanding the getJSON tool as I cannot get any content to load up in my `.quote` div.

Can anyone explain why this isn't working?

---

I am try to follow from this (separate) example which is indeed working:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
      $.getJSON("/json/cats.json", function(json) {
        $(".message").html(JSON.stringify(json));
      });

    });

  });
</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <h2>Cat Photo Finder</h2>
  </div>
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <div class = "col-xs-12 well message">
      The message will go here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <div class = "col-xs-12">
      <button id = "getMessage" class = "btn btn-primary">
        Get Message
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: See [`getJSON()` cross-domain errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849802/jquery-getjson-works-locally-but-not-cross-domain) for more info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your console for errors:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access.

You cannot make AJAX requests to a service hosted on a domain separate from your own unless *they* specifically allow it. This message indicates that it is not allowed.

Perhaps it's allowed in certain circumstances; check their documentation. If it's not, you'll have to *proxy* the request through your own server. There's no guarantee it's allowed in that situation either. You may have to provide them something like an API key or get added to a whitelist.

Comment: Just beat me to it!

Comment: Okay thanks Jacob, that makes sense as even this simple example copied  almost exactly from the jQuery documentation does not work:http://codepen.io/scabbyjoe/pen/bZQrRg

So in order to keep working on this I will need to test locally?

Comment: Yep, or try to proxy through your own local server, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Your can discover the error message in console panel:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

You should make sure the api.forismatic.com serve the resource with cross domain allowed.

Or you could take a look of [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#crossDomain) `crossDomain` option

---